# Problem with tests for deploy an apex class, probably bad configuration

Tags: salesforce

When I try to deploy a new apex class from a sandbox, I get the follow problems:

SFDCAccessControllerTest    testAccessControl_runAs System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Should not succeed as Survey__c is not accessible to standard user

Stack Trace: Class.SFDCAccessControllerTest.testAccessControl_runAs: line 58, column 1
Utilities_Test  getInstance System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: , Actual: xxxx.
Stack Trace: Class.Utilities_Test.getInstance: line 18, column 1

I suppose it's only a bad configuration, but I'm relative new with salesforce and don't know where I can disabled both test or change permissions for Survey__c and fix the problem with the instance name withouth affect the production eviroment.

I looked for similar cases and could not find it, please can anyone guide me.

Comment: According to your situation I think the user for which you have tried to run your test have not the permission of read or write on Survey__c. So I will recommend you to got to your org where you want to deploy the class then setup -> search for users -> find your user -> edit -> note down the profile -> go back -> search for profile -> search the profile you noted -> edit -> scroll down -> you will find object permissions -> find your object or object in which your field is there -> check the read and write box (as per your requirement) -> save.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say anything without the test's source code. Do they create a dummy user with "Standard User" profile or try to query existing user? From what I remember you can't edit standard profiles, you have to clone them so I don't know how would you or colleague manage to add Read permission... But check the profile mentioned in the test -> object permissions -> Survey -> read right.

It is also possible to deploy to production without running all tests. It's bit tricky, you need to specify the classes you want to run, you could skip that unit test. But everything you pick need to pass the rules (75% coverage minimum etc). If you need to deploy to prod ASAP it could help but well, you need to eventually bite the bullet and check what exactly is wrong with the test.